# BootStrap Popover 5.0 not displaying

Tags: bootstrap-5

When using the latest bootstrap popover, the data-bs-content not showing when hovering the second time. Does anyone solve this issue?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="tab" tabindex="0" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-container="body" 
data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs- 
content="<ul class='list mb-0'>
           <li>Disease Prediction</li>
           <li>Lead Identification &amp; Optimization</li>
           <li>Exploratory Safety &amp; Toxicology</li>
         </ul>">
<img src="image/area.png" class="my-3" alt="Pre- 
Discover" width="70">
    <h5 class="area-title">Discovery</h5>
</div>
```

I am using the script :

```
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs- 
toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
});
```

Comment: I've switched to drop-down :)
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have to add the inizialize part of the code AFTER the specific popover object.

EXAMPLE:

```
<!--POPOVER-->
  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
  
<script>
            var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
            var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
              return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
            })
</script>
```

---

Also, you'll need to add the bootstrap library to the code:

EXAMPLE:

```
  <!--Javascript part-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous">
          </script>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In case you compile your bootstrap.bundle.min.js yourself you need to remove the reference to bootstrap. The edited js included in your bootstrap.bundle.min.js file would be:

```
const popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
popoverTriggerList.map(popoverTriggerEl => {
  return new Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

Also make sure you use the bootstrap 5 js file that includes popper.js